# Special characters Parsing error in xml dom in java

Tags: java, xml, dom

i am using org.w3c.dom in java to read an xml with the following function

```
try
        {
            cwNodes =  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("cw-page");
        }
        catch(Exception doe)
        {
            BusinessLogic.WriteLog("Exp msg: "+doe.getMessage());

        }
```

the xml is

```
<cw-page id='4545' num='1'>dlfdlkfsdf</cw-page>
```

it reads fine but when i pass the following xml

```
<cw-page id='4545' num='1'>dlfdlkfsdf&!@#%^*()</cw-page>
```

it doesnt read it, the exception essage is null as well, dont know what is wrong can anybody help, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&` cannot occur by itself in a XML document as it is used to start a [XML entity reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-references). Therefore, your XML document must contain `&amp;` and not `&` if a parser has to parse its contents correctly and return `&` in the text content. `&` is not the only character that XML parsers will fail to parse incorrectly if they are present on their own; there are other characters that must be present as the [predefined XML entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-predefined-ent) for parsing to occur correctly.

You should either correct the document, by using entity references or use CDATA sections to transport the special characters in the payload.